# Flask not storing session (cache)

Tags: python, google-chrome, caching, flask

I have a Python project built using Flask and I test displaying pages with google chrome. Today for no reason sessions and flashes stoped working correctly (objects doesn't save). But in other browsers or in chrom incognito mode it still works right. The only difference that I can found is request.headers['cookie']:

In chrom: tabstyle=raw-tab; csrftoken=...; _ga=GA1.1.x.x; order=...

In other browsers and in incognito mode: session=...

What could be the reason? Is it some kind of a caching problem?

My code:

app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(16)
```

views.py

```
@app.route('/add_item/<string:item_id>')
def add_item(item_id):
    item = get_item()[item_id]
    session.setdefault('container', {})
    session['container'].setdefault(item_id, item.copy())
    session['container'][item_id].setdefault('quantity', 0)
    session['container'][item_id]['quantity'] += 1
    session.modified = True
    return redirect(url_for('container'))


@app.route('/container')
def container():
    if 'container' in session:
        return render_template('container.html', item=session['container'])
    else:
        flash('It is empty!', category='danger')
        return redirect(url_for('catalog'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find the reason why these cookies were added to each request in chrome. But if you have the same problem, you can delete it like I did and all things will go right.

Press F12 -> Application -> Storage -> Cookies -> Localhost -> Clear all.

[image]